# IXYS Solid State Relay Datasheet question (Snubber Diode Required?)

Tags: diodes, datasheet, solid-state-relay, snubber

Here is the datasheet that I have a question about.
http://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/CPC1907B.pdf/$file/CPC1907B.pdf

It states in the Features List on first page.
"Arc-Free With No Snubbing Circuits"

Does this mean that I do not need to add a Diode in reverse Parallel with my load?
And it will be fine without it?
I am driving an Inductive Load. 12VDC Motor Brake. 2-3amps.

There are no example circuits in Datasheet.

Comment: sounds like marketing hype.

Comment: did you ever get an answer on what does it actually means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the catch diode.

You must not exceed the absolute maximum blocking voltage stated in the datasheet (60V at 25 degrees C) and without a diode you will almost surely exceed that voltage when you switch off a solenoid load.

**Also** minimize the inductance of the wires running to the load (keep them together and minimize the length).